# How can i solve this problem when i train a transformer model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

faced an error, when i call this function **train_bert** :
`train_bert(net, criterion, opti, lr, lr_scheduler, train_loader, val_loader, epochs, iters_to_accumulate)`

The error is:
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'`

The implementation of the train function is as follows:

```
def train_bert(net, criterion, opti, lr, lr_scheduler, train_loader, val_loader, epochs, iters_to_accumulate): 
 
best_loss = np.Inf 
best_ep = 1 
nb_iterations = len(train_loader) 
print_every = nb_iterations // 5  # print the training loss 5 times per epoch 
iters = [] 
train_losses = [] 
val_losses = [] 
 
scaler = GradScaler() 
 
for ep in range(epochs): 
 
    net.train() 
    running_loss = 0.0 
    for it, (seq, attn_masks, token_type_ids, labels) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)): 
 
        # Converting to cuda tensors 
        seq, attn_masks, token_type_ids, labels = \ 
            seq.to(device), attn_masks.to(device), token_type_ids.to(device), labels.to(device) 
 
        # Enables autocasting for the forward pass (model + loss) 
        with autocast(): 
            # Obtaining the logits from the model 
            logits = net(seq, attn_masks, token_type_ids) 
 
            # Computing loss 
            loss = criterion(logits.squeeze(-1), labels.float()) 
            loss = loss / iters_to_accumulate  # Normalize the loss because it is averaged 
 
        # Backpropagating the gradients 
        # Scales loss.  Calls backward() on scaled loss to create scaled gradients. 
        scaler.scale(loss).backward() 
 
        if (it + 1) % iters_to_accumulate == 0: 
            # Optimization step 
            # scaler.step() first unscales the gradients of the optimizer's assigned params. 
            # If these gradients do not contain infs or NaNs, opti.step() is then called, 
            # otherwise, opti.step() is skipped. 
            scaler.step(opti) 
            # Updates the scale for next iteration. 
            scaler.update() 
            # Adjust the learning rate based on the number of iterations. 
            lr_scheduler.step() 
            # Clear gradients 
            opti.zero_grad() 
 
 
        running_loss += loss.item() 
 
        if (it + 1) % print_every == 0:  # Print training loss information 
            print() 
            print("Iteration {}/{} of epoch {} complete. Loss : {} " 
                  .format(it+1, nb_iterations, ep+1, running_loss / print_every)) 
 
            running_loss = 0.0 
 
 
    val_loss = evaluate_loss(net, device, criterion, val_loader)  # Compute validation loss 
    print() 
    print("Epoch {} complete! Validation Loss : {}".format(ep+1, val_loss)) 
 
    if val_loss < best_loss: 
        print("Best validation loss improved from {} to {}".format(best_loss, val_loss)) 
        print() 
        net_copy = copy.deepcopy(net)  # save a copy of the model 
        best_loss = val_loss 
        best_ep = ep + 1 
 

path_to_model='models/{}_lr_{}_val_loss_{}_ep_{}.pt'.format(bert_model, lr, round(best_loss, 5), best_ep) 
torch.save(net_copy.state_dict(), path_to_model) 
print("The model has been saved in {}".format(path_to_model)) 
 
del loss 
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

**Please help me i struggle with this problem for weeks:(**

Comment: One of the variables seq, attn_masks, token_type_ids, labels is a tuple when you do not expect it to be a tuple.

Comment: May explain more? i checked the code multiple time and try too many solutions and there is no result

Comment: Not really, we do not  know what these variables contain, did you print their types? their values? You should do the debugging as you are sitting in front of the code.

Comment: You are trying to send the variables `seq, attn_masks, token_type_ids, labels` to a device using `.to(device)`. Python is telling you that at least one of those variables is a `tuple` and therefore doesn't have a `to` method. You need to figure out which of your variables is not a tensor and then look at the dataset and potentially the collate function used by the `DataLoader` (if a custom one is used) and understand why.